# suitable method found for println (String, Int)

Tags: java

I am a novice programmer taking an intro to programming course and I have to come up with a program that creates the minimum number of coins for a number entered between 1-99.

I have done this, now I'm trying to output those coins.

```
scanner Userinput = new Scanner(System.in);

int stuff = Userinput.nextInt();
int q = stuff/quarters;
String A = "Number of Quarters";

System.out.println(A,q);
```

Now what I want to happen is the output to look like this

Number of Quarters: (whatever my number of quarters is)

I can get it to work by doing

```
System.out.println("Number of Quarters:");
System.out.println(q);
```

And it outputs as

```
Number of Quarters:
(quarters)
```

I need them to be right next to one another but cannot figure out how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

> The Java language provides special support for the string
>   concatenation operator ( + ), and for conversion of other objects to
>   strings

You can modify A to store directly the result q :

```
String A = "Number of Quarters: "+q;
System.out.println(A);
```

Or print it directly:

`System.out.println(A+" "+q);`

Comment: Thank you very much, this is epic and helps me out alot *bows

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to concatenating `q` and `"Number of Quarters: "` beforehand:

```
System.out.print("Number of Quarters: ");
System.out.println(q);
```

Answer (score 0):

[**System.out**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) is an instance of class [**PrintStream**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html).
`PrintStream` class doesn't have method `println(String, int)`.
You should use another method, e.g. [println(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.String%29) or [println(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28int%29)

```
System.out.println(A);
System.out.println(q);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `System.out.println()` function automatically prints a new line character at the end of the line to be printed. That is why you are getting the output in two lines. To avoid the terminating newline character while printing, you can use the `System.out.print()` function or the `System.out.printf()` function.

```
System.out.print("Number of quarters: ");
System.out.println(q);
```

OR

```
System.out.printf("Number of quarters : %s\n", q);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way besides concatenation

```
System.out.print("Number of Quarters: ");
System.out.print(q);
```

Use `print` instead of `println`

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use printf instead of println with this you can print the same what you want n from next onwards dont use println when you wants to print more than one output